# Getting "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" during "Load data local infile" in Docker/RDS

Tags: mysql, docker, rds, load-data-infile

I am encountering a really weird issue when running `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from a Docker container. The file that I am trying to load is essentially a single row file with 3 columns none of which are big.

As soon as I hit enter for the below command:
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/small_file.txt' INTO TABLE Some_Table COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' lines terminated BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;`

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

The next query I run gives the message:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away   
No connection. Trying to reconnect...  
Connection id:    4082  
Current database: Some Database
```

Some important differences between other questions which have similar issues and the issue I am facing are:

1. The file is tiny, it could not have exceed the default max_allowed_packet
2. There is no delay between the time the I hit the enter key and the time when the error message shows up, its instantaneous
3. Other regular select queries run fine
4. This happens only inside the Docker container(`FROM php:5.6-apache`), not in the host system which is a Mac

Interestingly enough, a container running from the same image in a AWS EC2 instance does not face issue, which leads me to believe it's more of a networking/configuration issue. Any pointers on how I should debug this?

Edit: The MySQL server is AWS RDS MySQL

Comment: What MySQL client are you using to run this query?

Comment: @Thomasleveil  `mysql --version` output: `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: Please post the content of '/tmp/small_file.txt' and TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE Some_Table; as well as result of SHOW INDEX FROM Some_Table; and 200 lines before and 200 lines after event was recorded in your error.log for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem (tiny file, no delay, other queries OK). We found that Intrusion Prevention System blocked the connection.

Comment: Additional note: This block was probably triggered by an abrupt change of the size of imported dataset (from 1.2 GB to 1.7 GB). After that, even tiny files were blocked.